# How to remove search bar from a wordpress theme?

Tags: theme-development, themes, search, design

How to remove search bar from a wordpress theme?

Comment: Where is the search bar located? In the sidebar, header, footer? Which theme are you using?

Answer (score 9):

If the search field is implemented as a widget, this can be done via the administration interface. Just navigate to Appearance > Widgets and drag the search widget from the widget area to the "Available Widgets" pane.

If the search field is hard-coded into the theme, it might be easier to edit the CSS rather than the HTML and PHP. Here's how:

- Use [Firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com/) or a similar tool to locate the DIV element containing the search code.
- In the theme's CSS file (probably style.css), add `display: none` to that DIV. That's it!

This is a minimally invasive approach. If you ever want to re-enable the search bar, just remove the `display: none` statement from your CSS.

Comment: Thanks, it will be great idea. I am just going to implement it.

Comment: @kylan +1 for the CSS idea. This is especially great for child themes which are made of one file only: `style.css`.

Answer (score 4):

1. Try to locate the HTML representing the search bar.
2. Then find in which theme files it resides (it may be defined in multiple files - single.php, page.php,..)
3. Remove the markup including the php call from all the files.

Answer (score 3):

You can find it at header.php and just delete it or use CSS attribute **"display:none"**. **get_search_form()** method represents Search Bar.

```
<?php
// Has the text been hidden?
if ( 'blank' == get_header_textcolor() ) : ?>

    <div class="only-search<?php if ( $header_image ) : ?> with-image<?php endif; ?>">
    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
    </div>
    <?php
        else :
    ?>
    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```